# Binding heading indent to paragraph

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to solve this problem using CSS or do I have to fix it on per-article basis by adding newlines? I have article structure:

```
<div>
    <img style="float: left" src="image_src.jpg">
    <h3>Heading #1</h3>
    <p>Paragraph 1....</p>
    <h3>Heading #2</h3>
    <p>Paragraph 2....</p>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is that very often heading "catches" the image and has to be indented while it's paragraph appears below it. Here is an example:

[image]

Is there a way I can force heading to go below the image, following it's paragraph or do I have to add newlines manually whenever I have such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use the CSS `nth-of-type` selector to clear the float on all but the first h3 element.

```
h3:nth-of-type(n+2){
    clear:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BTFyg/)**

Comment: Ugh, I guess this will have to work. Its a bit more elegant than putting `<br>`, but if picture is higher and there are 2 small paragraphs, it would create pretty big empty space.